# Trying to copy an xlsb worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I want to copy an entire worksheet to another (specific Worksheet) workbook.
The source worksheet is in .xlsb format.
Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i have modified my answer to make it as dynamic as possible. The first section of code you see below achieves the following:

> **Browse a file that the source sheet needs to be copied to**

This will search through the entire directory for the file

```
'UDF for finding a file no matter where it is located, providing it is within the HostFolders minimum location criteria
'The first function checks if the scripting runtime reference is enabled on hosts computer, and if not, enables it so that the FileSytemObject may be created
'The second function will find a specified file by begining with the intial stated HostFolder, and then go through all subfolders until it has found the file


Option Explicit
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String
Dim Ref As Object, CheckRefEnabled%

Sub FindFile()

HostFolder = "Insert folder path here\" 'Change this HostFolder to suit preference

CheckRefEnabled = 0
With ThisWorkbook
    For Each Ref In .VBProject.References
        If Ref.Name = "Scripting" Then
            CheckRefEnabled = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Ref
    If CheckRefEnabled = 0 Then
        .VBProject.References.AddFromFile ("C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll")
    End If
End With

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
Next

Dim File
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If File.Name = "insert name of file here.xlsb" Then
        Workbooks.Open (Folder.Path & "\" & File.Name), UpdateLinks:=False
        Workbooks(File.Name).Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The next part of the code achieves the following:

> **Copies the worksheet in ThisWorkbook to the newly opened workbook, saves it, and closes it**

```
Option Explicit
Dim w As Workbook

Sub sheetCopy()

Set w = ThisWorkbook

'amend this to suit your workbook names and sheet names
w.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Workbooks("workbook name").Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

So, finally **Run the full code below to complete everything**:

```
Option Explicit
Dim w As Workbook

Sub sheetCopy()

Set w = ThisWorkbook
FindFile

'amend this to suit your workbook names and sheet names
w.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Workbooks("workbook name").Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this.But to further explain my requirement. I need to browse a file to copy and then copy the same to a specific workbook(closed workbook)

Comment: what is the name of the file? is it always the same?

Comment: the source file (the file to be copied can be different) but the closed workbook is always the same

Comment: insert the name of the close workbook in this part of the code 'If File.Name = "insert name of file here.xlsb" Then' . You also then need to insert the name of the closed workbook in the main code : 'w.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Workbooks("workbook name").Sheets(1)'

Comment: the sheetCopy sub and FindFile sub need to be inserted into the source file

Comment: Thanks for this..Also,is there any means to paste special values in this?

Comment: No Problem! :), did you have any issues running the code? for paste values, just copy and paste the whole sheet i.e. copy sheet then paste values. The code for pastevalues is " range("A:V").copy" then "range("A:V").pastespecial xlpastevalues" <<< this is just an illustrative example